# Inner product over finite field

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory, inner-product

sorry for informals but is my first post.
In Coding theory (exactly in *Coding theory a first course* - San ling and Chaoping) found this definition:

$\langle , \rangle :\mathbb{F}_q^n\times\mathbb{F}_q^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_q$ is *inner product* on $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ if satisfaying the following conditions: for all $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\in \mathbb{F}_q^n$
(a) $\langle\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle=\langle\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{w}\rangle+\langle\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle$
(b) $\langle\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}\rangle=\langle\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}\rangle+\langle\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{w}\rangle$
(c) $\langle\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}\rangle=0$ for all $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbf{F}_q^n$ if and only if $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$;
(d) $\langle\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}\rangle=0$ for all $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbf{F}_q^n$ if and only if $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$.

The first thing that strikes me is **¿ that no property about scalar ?** however, in all inner product (in Finite fields) i know there is a property in scalar: $\exists \sigma\in Aut(\mathbb{F}_q)$ such that $\forall \mathbf{u},\mathbf{w}\in \mathbb{F}_q^n,\ \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{F}_q,\langle \mathbf{u},\lambda \mathbf{w}\rangle=\sigma(\lambda)\langle\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{w}\rangle$, i dont know if it is possible be deducted from (a),(b),(c),(d) ?
And second, the theorem $\dim{C}+\dim{C^\perp}=n$ where $C$ is subespace in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ the proof use in particular $\langle \mathbf{u}.\mathbf{w}\rangle = \mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{w}$ (usual dot product), ¿ it is possible be deducted this theorem for any inner product ?
i.e. $\langle -,-\rangle$ satisfaying (a),(b),(c),(d) and $C^\perp=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{F}_q^n:\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{x}\rangle=0\ \forall \mathbf{u}\in C\}$ ¿then $\dim{C}+\dim{C^\perp}=n$ ? 
the inner products that I know are $\ell$-Galois inner product, (Hermitian and dot product are particular cases of these), and Sympletic (only $n$ even).

Comment: The quantification should be $\exists\sigma\forall u,v,\lambda$

Comment: Hmm. This seems more like a non-degenerate bilinear form / Hermitian form than an "inner product". To see what I mean, imagine replacing the role of finite fields with $\mathbb R$ and notice that you don't recover the usual definition of "inner product". Presumably you would need an axiom asserting the existence of something resembling an orthonormal basis to call this operation an inner product. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

The compatibility with scalars cannot be deduced. Simply view $\mathbb{F}_q$ as $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space, pick a nondegenerate bilinear form with values in $\mathbb{F}_p$, and view it as $\mathbb{F}_q$-valued bilinear form via the inclusion. This satisfies all of the above, but cannot be compatible with scalars in any way since it only takes values in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

I also don't think that the dimension formula you're asking about holds without assuming something about compatibility with scalars. In fact, $C^{\perp}$ is not even necessarily a $\mathbb{F}_q$ subspace for an inner product as constructed above.